# Bug Report Captured

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5

I have a Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.1 and I get several "Bug Report Captured" notifications every day. I want to never ever get these again.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, bug reports are intended to use by developers to know what is causing the problem/bug while developing or modifying the apps. A bug report captures all the relevant data needed for the developer to analyze the bugs.

Use the following steps to disable USB Debugging in Developer options which might capture bug reports.

1. Go to Settings and scroll to the bottom of the menu
2. If you see "Developer options" go to step 5
3. If you do not see Developer options, select About phone, scroll to the bottom of the menu
4. Press "Build number" seven times, this will make you a developer.
5. Go back and scroll to the bottom of Settings
6. Enter Developer options menu
7. Uncheck USB debugging

You've now deactivated the Bug Reports.

Let me know in the comments if that didn't work.

Comment: But what if I am actually a developer? I need USB debugging daily but don't want this messages to pop up...

Comment: @SapuSeven USB Debugging does need bug reports to be captured.

Comment: Isn't there any way of disabling bug reports with USB debugging enabled on a rooted phone?

Comment: @SapuSeven it's totally off topic from the original question. So, please post a new question

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic at all. I have the same question as OP, but your answer doesn't help me.

Comment: @SapuSeven The "Bug Report Captured" is a default `Toast` message from `android` functionality and there is no easy way to disable this without disabling "USB Debugging".